# Unable to post messages using Mailbox API and Mojo::UserAgent

Tags: perl, mailgun, mojo-useragent

According to the API docs (https://documentation.mailgun.com/api-sending.html) all the relevant parameters are supplied, but it gives me

> 400 response: BAD REQUEST

Here's my piece of code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Mojo::UserAgent;
use MIME::Base64;
use JSON qw(to_json);

use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;

my $ua = Mojo::UserAgent->new;
my $endpoint = 'https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandbox2ad5b70fd744416ea7ff3d5422YYYYYY.mailgun.org/messages';

my $key = 'key-d3d8d350d4ef9c92349df62208XXXXXX';
my $headers = { 'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . encode_base64('api:' . $key)  };
my $params = {
    'to' => 'abc@domain.ru',
    'subject' => 'testing',
    'text' => 'some text',
    'from' => 'postmaster@sandbox2ad5b70fd744416ea7ff3d5422YYYYYY.mailgun.org'
};

my $tx = $ua->post($endpoint, $headers, json => $params);
my $res = $tx->success;
if ($res) {
    say $res->body;
} else {
    my $err = $tx->error;
    die "$err->{code} response: $err->{message}" if $err->{code};
    die "Connection error: $err->{message}";
}
```

I have Mojo version as follows:

> CORE
>
> Perl        (v5.22.1, linux)
>
> Mojolicious (7.26, Doughnut)
>
> OPTIONAL
>
> EV 4.0+                 (4.22)
>
> IO::Socket::Socks 0.64+ (0.67)
>
> IO::Socket::SSL 1.94+   (2.024)
>
> Net::DNS::Native 0.15+  (n/a)

I wrote another version of this script using `LWP::UserAgent` and it works fine.

Are there some Mojo::UserAgent experts who might have an idea of what is wrong with the script?

**UPDATED**

Here's my `LWP::UserAgent` version which works without problems:

```
my ($key, $domain, $from, $from_name, $to, $subject, $comments) = @_;

my $url = 'https://api.mailgun.net/v3';
$url = $url . '/' . $domain . '/messages';  

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->default_header('Authorization' => 'Basic ' . encode_base64('api:' . $key));

my $data = {
      to => $to,
      subject => $subject,
      text => $comments,
      from =>  $from_name . '<' . $from . '>'        
};

my $r = $ua->post($url, Content => $data);
my $rc = $r->code; 
if ($rc == 200) {
    my $hash = from_json($r->decoded_content);
    say $hash->{id};
    say $hash->{message};       
} else {
    return { error => $rc };
}
```

**UPDATED ON 25.02.2017**

I used fake requests to my `localhost:9000`. Here's what I've traced using `nc -l 9000`:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
TE: deflate,gzip;q=0.3
Connection: TE, close
Authorization: Basic YXBpOmtleS1kM2Q4ZDM1MGQ0ZWY5YzkyMzQ5ZGY2MjIwOGRXXXXXX== 
Host: localhost:9000
User-Agent: libwww-perl/6.15
Content-Length: 144
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

text=%3Chtml%3E%3Cbody%3E%3Cp%3Etest%3C%2Fp%3E%3C%2Fbody%3E%3C%2Fhtml%3E&from=John%3Clala%40ya.ru%3E&to=zozoba29a%40yandex.ru&subject=My+Subject
```

And:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9000
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Authorization: Basic YXBpOmtleS1kM2Q4ZDM1MGQ0ZWY5YzkyMzQ5ZGY2MjIwOGRjXXXXXX==

Content-Length: 144
User-Agent: Mojolicious (Perl)

from=John%3Clala%40ya.ru%3E&subject=My+Subject&text=%3Chtml%3E%3Cbody%3E%3Cp%3Etest%3C%2Fp%3E%3C%2Fbody%3E%3C%2Fhtml%3E&to=zozoba29a%40yandex.ru
```

Comment: Can you show your LWP::UserAgent script as well please?

Comment: @simbabque I updated my question.

Comment: The `from` field has different content.

Comment: yes, I tried that "format", it had no impact.

Comment: Please make sure you have the exact same thing in both versions so we don't waste time trying things you already tried.

Comment: Apart from different `from` field the Mojo version uses a JSON body while the LWP version behaves like a form submission, i.e. `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. I cannot see from the documentation that a JSON submission is accepted at all.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I already tried `my $tx = $ua->post($url, $headers, form => $params);` instead, it didn't change anything at all. Please correct me if I am submitting a form improperly.

Comment: @varnie: I just pointed out that your non-working Mojo version does  obviously different things than the working LWP version. I recommend that you let it do exactly the same things (i.e. same from etc) first so that you can better find out what difference causes the problems. Finding the cause of a problem when changing lots of things at the same time is much harder than finding it when only changing few things.

Comment: It might also be helpful to dump out the full request with headers and body for both of the programs and compare.

Comment: @simbabque I provided the dumped data.

Comment: The mojo request doesn't have a body, but it has a content length header. Did you forget to copy that or is it missing?

Comment: Ouch, my bad. I forgot to paste it. Updated again.